# Solana mobile sdk seed vault unauthorized

Tags: wallet, seed, mobile, vault

We are trying to make a wallet compatible with the Solana Mobile SDK seed vault, but it's throwing an error? Does anyone know what is wrong here? See the screenshot attached.

[image: No seed remaining to be authorized for purpose_sign_solana_transaction]

Comment: please crop the dead space from the screenshot and add the complete error message in a code block as text to improve the quality of this question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be for one of several reasons:

1. Do you have the `impl` project installed? It provides the reference implementation of the Seed Vault APIs, which are consumed by the fakewallet app. One thing to watch out for - due to the way Android permissions work, make sure to install the `impl` APK *first*, followed by the `fakewallet` APK.
2. Have you created a seed in the `impl` project? There's a `+` icon in the toolbar that you can use to create a new seed.
3. You've found a bug - if neither 1 nor 2 fixes your problem, please capture logcat output from `impl` and `fakewallet` and post it here, and I will review it.